# How do I change to the texture mode in the viewport shading menu

Tags: interface

I have just switched from the old UI (Version 2.7x) and I can't find the viewport shading menu so I can switch to texture shading.

[image: the mode i want to enter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a dumb question :).
Since Blender 2.8, it's called *Material Preview*.
It's the third icon in the *Viewport shading*.

[image]